# Bootstrap Date Range Picker issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I have two input boxes for the pickup date and return date. when I click on the pickup input box double month view calendar will display and after selecting the range first date goes to pickup input and second goes to return input box. This two input boxes should display same calendar. But problem is...
When I select the date range in first input box that selected range will highlight. But again when I open return input box calendar that doesn't highlight selected range. How can I do that?

Comment: show your code or better create jsfiddle

Comment: $('#datepicker1').daterangepicker();
$('#datepicker2').daterangepicker();